# Scala String Trim

Tags: json, scala

I am trying to strip the string {"$outer":{},  (starts from curly brace and end with comma) in my input but I could not do it.

My input is like below

```
{"$outer":{},"size":"10","query":{"$outer":{},"match":{"$outer":{},"_all":{"$outer":{},"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}}
```

I tried the below ways but both did not help me.

First Approach:

```
val dropString = "\"$outer\":{},"
val payLoadTrim = payLoadLif.dropWhile(_ == dropString).reverse.dropWhile(_ == dropString).reverse
```

This one did not do anything. Here is the output:

```
{"$outer":{},"size":"10","query":{"$outer":{},"match":{"$outer":{},"_all":{"$outer":{},"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}}
```

Second Approach:

```
def stripAll(s: String, bad: String): String = {
@scala.annotation.tailrec def start(n: Int): String = 
    if (n == s.length) ""
    else if (bad.indexOf(s.charAt(n)) < 0) end(n, s.length)
    else start(1 + n)

@scala.annotation.tailrec def end(a: Int, n: Int): String =
    if (n <= a) s.substring(a, n)
    else if (bad.indexOf(s.charAt(n - 1)) < 0) s.substring(a, n)
    else end(a, n - 1)

  start(0)
}
```

Output from Second:

```
size":"10","query":{"$outer":{},"match":{"$outer":{},"_all":{"$outer":{},"query":"VALLE","operator":"
```

and Desired Output:

```
{"size":"10","query":{"match":{"_all":{"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `replace`:

```
val input = """{"$outer":{},"size":"10","query":{"$outer":{},"match":{"$outer":{},"_all":{"$outer":{},"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}}"""

input.replace("\"$outer\":{},", "")
```

which returns:

```
{"size":"10","query":{"match":{"_all":{"query":"VALLE","operator":"and"}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to cut off an exact prefix/suffix you can use [`.stripPrefix`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#stripPrefix(prefix:String):String)/[`.stripSuffix`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#stripSuffix(suffix:String):String) methods:

```
@ "abcdef".stripPrefix("abc")
res: String = "def"
@ "abcdef".stripSuffix("def")
res: String = "abc"
```

Note that if the string doesn't have such prefix (or suffix), it will stay unchanged:

```
@ "abcdef".stripPrefix("foo")
res: String = "abcdef"
@ "abcdef".stripSuffix("buh")
res: String = "abcdef"
```

Sometimes it's important to cut off from the beginning (or end), so if when you use `.replace`, you should be careful and add `^...` (or `...$`) to the regex pattern, otherwise it may find a match somewhere in the middle and replace it.

---

Bonus: if you just want to check that a string has a given prefix/suffix, you can use [`.startsWith`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#stripSuffix(suffix:String):String)/[`.endsWith`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#stripSuffix(suffix:String):String) methods (plus `.startsWith` can also take an offset).